# sql filter table data

Tags: php, sql, filter

I  have a table with more than 10 columns. I can filter data with `sql` command like:

```
mysql_select_db("mydb", $con);

$sql="SELECT * FROM files WHERE PUB LIKE '".$PUB."' AND
ID LIKE '".$ID."' AND PG_NO LIKE '%".$PG_NO."%' AND
SECTION LIKE '".$SECTION."' AND EDITION LIKE '%".$EDITION."%' AND
COLOR LIKE '".$COLOR."' AND REVISION LIKE '".$REVISION."'";
```

The problem is I have to fill every field of search/filter query.
I want to sometimes use all the fields and some of the fields some other times.

Is there any way that I can filter with only 1 or 2 filter criteria and rest filters are left blank to show all corresponding data?

Answer (score 0):

Add this to before you call your SQL statement

```
if(isset($PUB)){}
else{
    $PUB = "%";
    }
if(isset($ID)){}
else{
    $ID = "%";
    }   
if(isset($SECTION)){}
else{
    $SECTION = "%";
    }
if(isset($EDITION)){}
else{
    $EDITION = "%";
    }
if(isset($COLOR)){}
else{
    $COLOR = "%";
    }
if(isset($REVISION)){}
else{
    $REVISION = "%";
    }
```

What we are essentially doing is giving all the criteria wildcard signs if no option was chosen.

Comment: <form action="x.php">
<input name="PUB"><input name="ID">~
<input type="submit">
<?php
$PUB=$_REQUEST['PUB'];$ID=$_REQUEST['ID'];~
if(isset($PUB)){}else{$PUB = "%";}
if(isset($ID)){}else{$ID = "%";}~
mysql_select_db("mydb",$con);
$sql="SELECT * FROM files WHERE PUB LIKE '".$PUB."' AND ID LIKE '".$ID."'~;
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
echo $row['FULL'];
echo "<table><tr><th>PUB</th><th>ID</th>~</tr>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{echo "<tr>";echo "<td>".$row['PUB']."</td>";echo "<td>".$row['ID']."</td>";~
echo "</tr>";}echo "</table>";?>

Comment: sorry the space problem made me write this in clumsy way. i feel both of you are doing the right thing, just i cant get the thing going. here is the total code i am using, ~ denotes the rest like parts. pls help.